# Using C Keywords in C++

Tags: c++, c, keyword, difference

So I was wondering why C++ allows for C keywords to be used. After all, `printf("Hello, World!\n");` does the same thing as `cout << "Hello, World!\n";`. Is one returned to the processsor faster than the other? Or are there some keywords in C that you may need in C++? (P.S: This question is out of sheer curiosity)

Comment: `printf` isn't a keyword, it's a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because C++ was designed to allow for as much compatability with C code as possible. It allows it to be more extensible, and easily adopted into applications previously written in pure C.

Comment: That does make sense, considering a C++ compiler would allow you to write an entire program in C, correct?

Comment: For the most part yes. But when in C++, it is mostly recommended to do things with C++ stlye.

Answer (score 4):

C++ wasn't envisioned as a separate language from C; it grew out of "C with Classes". Every further revision to C++ maintained backward compatibility whenever it was reasonably practical. It's not particularly impractical to keep the C standard library around, so there it is.

Answer (score 2):

Because C++ was supposed to be backward compatible with C.

Answer (score 1):

They're not keywords; they're function and class names from the Standard Library.

The C library (with a few modifications) is available as part of the C++ library; so you can call C library functions like `printf` from a C++ program if you want.